# How to pass login credentials to initial screen of DrawerMenu of navigation drawer in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have created React-navigation Drawer V3 in my app. I am facing the problem of getting the login credentials on the initial screen that is the "Home" screen of my drawer navigation stack. Although I am passing the data on DrawerMenu.js from Login.js with the help of :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerMenu', {
    loginData: loginData
})
```

and getting the data on DrawerMenu.js with :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loginData: props.navigation.state.params.loginData
    }
  }
```

But I need to get this data to Home.js which I am not able to get. The reason of getting the data to DrawerMenu.js was because there are several other screens in the stack which want the logindata and they are able to get it using screenProps used in drawer content component but as Home is the initial screen so there no way that it receives the data on the first time, only the DrawerMenu.js file receives it initially. Can someone help me out on this?

Here is my code of DrawerMenu with navigation stack.

```js
class DrawerMenu extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loginData: props.navigation.state.params.loginData
    }
  }


  static navigationOptions =
    {
      header: null,
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.droidSafeArea}>
        <MyApp screenProps={{ loginData: this.state.loginData}} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

class Hidden extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}


const MainScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  Home: { screen: Home },
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  },
  Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3
  }
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  });

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainScreenNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: <Hidden />
      }
    }
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: 300,

    contentComponent: DrawerComponent
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

export default DrawerMenu;
```

I am using :

```
"react-native" : "0.57.5",
 "react": "16.6.1",
 "react-navigation": "^3.5.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AsyncStorage` to save the data 
**To store**

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Key Value', 'Item Value');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

**To retrieve**

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Key Value');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Or you can use **`redux`**.